# Count how many elements are in table with getelemtentsbyid

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I need to define my last `iRow` inside a table as shown in picture. The table is generated out of a filter so the number of rows vary each time.

The code I am using is to download and save every element in this table but sometimes it workes perfectly and sometimes is gets stuck because there are less than 20 elements hence I need to define the last one.

At first I tried to avoid the debug with `on error goto` or `on error resume next` statements but somehow they fail. Currently I have set the last `iRow to 20` but I want to change this to be less buggy.

Here is my full code for this piece but only the first part is of interest:

```
Dim TableName As String
Dim myURL As String
'Dim element As Object


    For iRow = 0 To 20  --> I need to define my last iRow
        TableName = "docTypeForm:documentTbl:" & iRow & ":j_idt250"
        'Set element = obJIE.document.getelementbyid("docTypeForm:documentTbl:tb")
        'MsgBox element.count
        On Error GoTo LastFile
                myURL = obJIE.document.getelementbyid(TableName).getelementsbytagname("a")
               ' MsgBox myURL.count

        On Error GoTo LastFile
        TitleJob = obJIE.document.getelementbyid(TableName).innerText

                Dim WinHttpReq As Object
                     Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                     WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
                     WinHttpReq.Send


                     myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
                             If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
                                 Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
                                 oStream.Open
                                 oStream.Type = 1
                                 oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
                                 oStream.SaveToFile (MAIN_FOLDER & "\files\" & TitleJob & ".xml")
                                 oStream.Close
                             End If
    next
    LastFile:
```

[image]
the "tbl:0,1,2" are the rows

Comment: This _myURL = obJIE.document.getelementbyid(TableName).getelementsbytagname("a")_ should fail because it returns a collection (object) not a string. You need the _Set_ keyword in front for object reference and declare as object or appropriate HTMLElementCollection type.

Comment: And change the variable name to something more appropriate.

Comment: The code saves the files in the correct location but goes in error because of the `to 20` statement. I only need to return how many element are present.
For this example if I set `iRow = 0 to 2` it runs without errors. So I just need to define my last iRow

Comment: I think update the question then to focus only on that problem and any associated errors. If you need to dynamically determine iRow why not just take the count of tr elements in the table ?

Comment: I will get rid of the extra information in my question. The count of the tr elements is indeed what I'm looking for but I have no idea how to count them. I tried `.count` and `.Length` on different places with different settings but everytime I get an error that it is not supported

Comment: Select the table by its id then do table.getElementsByTagName("tr").Length

Comment: Great, I knew it was something with `.Length` but I was using it wrong. I ran the macro a few times with different senarios and it is free of errors! Thanks QHarr.

Comment: you are most welcome

Answer (score 1):

See comments for explanation. Solution was provided by QHarr

```
Dim TableName As String
Dim myURL As String
Dim element As Object
Dim LastEl As Object

Set LastEl = obJIE.document.getElementByid("docTypeForm:documentTbl:tb").getElementsByTagName("tr")

    For iRow = 0 To LastEl.Length - 1
        TableName = "docTypeForm:documentTbl:" & iRow & ":j_idt250"

        Set element = obJIE.document.getElementByid(TableName).getElementsByTagName("a")

        TitleJob = obJIE.document.getElementByid(TableName).innerText
        myURL = element
```